# What kind of assignment is this?

Tags: verilog, modelsim

I have this verilog code from my university course which implements a basic multiplier.

```
//this is a portion of the code.
reg [16:0] multiplicand_copy;
input [7:0] multiplicand;

multiplicand_copy = {9'd0, multiplicand}; // this line is my question
```

somewhere in the code there is this assignment using brackets that i can't understand.What kind of assignment is this and what's happening in this line ?I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
reg [16:0] multiplicand_copy; 
input [7:0] multiplicand; 
multiplicand_copy = {9'd0, multiplicand};
```

In this code snippet, `multiplicand` is 8 bits variable and `multiplicand_copy` is 17 bits variable.

`multiplicand_copy = {9'd0, multiplicand};` will do concatenation of 9 zeros and 8 bits of `multiplicand` and make assignment of 17 bits of `multiplicand_copy`.